# In-app purchase pop-up doesn't show instantly, but with a delay

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have the following code for in-app purchases.

Now whenever a specific button is clicked I execute: `IAPService.shared.purchase()`.

It works but the possibility for the user to purchase the product doesn't pop-up immediately - it somehow takes a while until the request is being processed. This delay leads to misunderstandings and several users spamming the button.

**Is there a way to display the purchase pop-up instantly** - I've seen other apps working without any delay.

```
class IAPService: NSObject {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    private override init() {}
    static let shared = IAPService()

    weak var delegate: CarViewController?

    var products = [SKProduct]()
    let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()

    private var purchasedProductIdentifiers: Set<String> = []

    func getProducts() {
        let product: Set = ["IDIDID"]
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: product)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
        paymentQueue.add(self)
    }

    func purchase() {
        guard let productToPurchase = products.first else { return }
        print(productToPurchase)
        let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
        paymentQueue.add(payment)
    }

    func restorePurchases() {
        paymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

}

extension IAPService: SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        self.products = response.products
        for product in response.products {
            print(product.localizedTitle)
        }
    }

}

extension IAPService: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
            if transaction.payment.productIdentifier == "IDIDID" && ( transaction.transactionState == .purchased || transaction.transactionState == .restored ) {
                premiumPurchased = true
                defaults.set(premiumPurchased, forKey: "premiumPurchased")
                print(premiumPurchased)
            }
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing: break
            case .purchased: goToAddCar(); queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            default: queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }
    }

    func goToAddCar() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddCar") as! AddCarViewController
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = controller
    }

}

extension SKPaymentTransactionState {
    func status() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .deferred: return "deferred"
        case .failed: return "failed"
        case .purchased: return "purchased"
        case .purchasing: return "purchasing"
        case .restored: return "restored"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the purchase pop-up on the main thread. Any UI changes you want to happen quickly should be put inside DispatchQueue.main block. E.g. inside the func goToAddCar(), wrap the code in a DispatchQueue.main.async block as follows

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async{

       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
          "AddCar") as! AddCarViewController
       UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = controller
    }
```